# Solution not working: is a namespace but is used as a type

Tags: c#, service, reference

I am trying to create a webservice consumer object in VS 2015 / C#, now I get the response that my object "is a namespace but is used like a type".

There are many earlier version of this question where the solution always is to give object a different name to the namespace it is in, to prevent confusion by the compiler. 
However I keep getting this problem even though I have very careful to give the reference a different name from the namespace?? This however, does not help..

I have many different configurations with "using" in different places, etc as suggested in other discussions, made no difference.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;


namespace TestApp_1
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public void DoeSchrijfActie()
        {

            StringBuilder sSql_1 = new StringBuilder();

            TestApp_1.BLADIBLUB MyServ = new TestApp_1.BLADIBLUB();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to tell us what line the error is on. Also, what is `BLADIBLUB`?

Comment: The error is in the line TestApp_1.BLADIBLUB MyServ = new TestApp_1.BLADIBLUB(); BLADIBLUB is the name I gave to the ServiceReference. I gave it a "striking" name to be 100% sure that there is no name-confusion

Comment: By the way: the ServiceReference is working.. it does connect to the referenced webservice..

Comment: The error is that when I run the debugger it keeps complaining: "Error CS0118 'BLADIBLUB' is a namespace but is used like a type TestApp_1" on line 23. BTW: the code may look a bit strange, but this is from frustration after many tries...

Comment: Please post the code of 'TestApp_1.BLADIBLUB'

Comment: Found it! I had to instantiate the "abstract class" TestApp_1.BLADIBLUB.EasyDOPSoap into a object. Did that by hand, works now! (Sorry for the bad English)

Answer (score 0):

Probably somewhere in your code you have a folder named *BLADIBLUB* and have a code file in it, which is creating a namespace by this name. This is the most common mistake that could be overlooked leading to this error, only other way being manually creating that namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! I had to instantiate the "abstract class" TestApp_1.BLADIBLUB.EasyDOPSoap into an object. Did that by hand, works now! (Sorry for the bad English)